# Waiting for useMutation status to show a modal based on error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tanstackreact-query, trpc

I'm using t3stack for my project (tailwind - typescipt- tRPC)
to use an api. in this app you do this for Example :

`const apiResult = api.story.generateStory.useMutation();`

no need to pass any function or key.

and to trigger this mutation:

`apiResult.mutate(passedData)`

today for project, after clicking a button that triggers mutate(), I needed to wait mutation to check if it returns 401 error, it shows up a modal. tried searching and most of answers were old or with useEffect. keep in mind I don't want to use useEffect. how can I wait for useMutation status and then show up a modal onClick (imagine modal is showed up by using elementRef.showModal())

Comment: You should be able to check the status code of the response. https://trpc.io/docs/server/error-handling

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me! first keep in mind that we have
`mutateAsync`
which works asynchronous. then we can use try, catch to open modal on error after clicking :

```
const handleClick = async () => {
  try {
   // Trigger the mutation
   await apiResult.mutateAsync(passedData);

   // Mutation was successful, do something
   console.log('Mutation success');
  } catch (error) {
   // Mutation failed, show error modal
   console.log('Mutation error:', error);
   modalRef.current.showModal();
 }
};
```